# Jetpack Compose Switch Toggle elevation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a white Switch on white background. The default switch toggle elevation seems to be to low which results in the toggle blending with the switch and background.
I know there is `Modifier.shadow` that can be applied to modifier, however Switch does not expose the toggle view and its modifier (as far as I figured). So is there a way to control the elevation in such a case?
[image]

This is what I want to achieve.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, but there's no easy solution for adding elevation without creating a custom composable. My solution was to change the Switch colors so it doesn't blend into the background. You can do that by modifying the `SwitchDefaults.colors`, and  in the simplest case, you just need to use a different `uncheckedThumbColor` (in my case, I changed it to a light blue-grey color):

```
        Switch(
            ...
            colors = SwitchDefaults.colors(
                uncheckedThumbColor = BlueGrey50
            )
            ...
        )
```

where `val BlueGrey50 = Color(0xFFeceff1)`